# Нужно сравнить значение ключа с массивом

Tags: reactjs

Не получается отсеивать сообщения, которые уже были получены.
массив всегда наполняется сообщением с последним индексом, но поидее туда должны попадать все. При получении нового сообщения массив перезаписывается новым id, а старый удаляется

```
function getMessage () {
api
  .getMessage()
  .then(res => {
    let idArr = []
    if (!idArr.includes(res[0].idMessage)) {
      idArr.push(res[0].idMessage)
      setMessages([
        { message: res[0].textMessage, ownMessage: false },
        ...messages
      ])
      console.log(res[0].idMessage) // BAE5E73CD474DE6A
      console.log(idArr) // ['BAE5E73CD474DE6A']
      console.log(res) // ключ-значение в объекте: idMessage: "BAE5E73CD474DE6A"
    } else {
      console.log(`Второй вызов ${idArr}`)
    }
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

}

Comment: если id повторяются внутри одного сообщения, то использование локальной переменной еще понятно. но если стоит задача в setMessages() не передавать повторно сообщения от getMessage(), то либо надо хранить глобально map из id, либо всегда передавать его аргументом в getMessage(). и странный фильтр только на одно сообщение, другие не нужны?

Comment: У меня метод из апи будет выводить последнее сообщение и что бы оно одно и тоже не приходило, вот такой способ я придумал

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему добавлением стейта для хранения id

```
const [idArr, setIdArr] = useState([])
const idArrCopy = Object.assign([], idArr)

function getMessage () {
api
  .getMessage()
  .then(res => {
    let idMessage = res[0].idMessage
    if (!idArrCopy.includes(idMessage)) {
      setMessages([
        { message: res[0].textMessage, ownMessage: false },
        ...messages
      ])
      idArrCopy.push(idMessage)
      setIdArr(idArrCopy)
    } else {
      console.log(`Такой Id уже есть: ${idArr}`)
    }
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

}